# Does $2^A\to 2^B$ produce a function $B\to A$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A, B$ be two sets such that there is a function $2^A\to2^B$ preserving unions and $\emptyset\mapsto\emptyset$ and $A\mapsto B$ and no singleton maps to $\emptyset$.
>   Does there exist a "canonical" function $B\to A$?
>   If not, what are the conditions that guarantee the existence of a such function?

I have no idea to attempt to this problem. First I tried to work with some explicit examples, but that does not help me to understand what is actually happening here. Can anybody help me to solve this problem? I do not need a complete solution, but enough explanation to understand the problem statement and some hint (if necessary).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $\{A\}\mapsto\{B\}$? $\{A\}$ is not, in general, a subset of $A$. Do you mean that the function maps $A$ to $B$? Or do you mean that the function maps singletons to singletons? Is the function injective? A bijection?

Comment: An idea could be to define $g: B\to A$ by specifying $g^{-1}(\{a\}) = f(\{a\})$  for $a \in A$

Comment: Ok, so singletons are mapped to singletons. Can they all be mapped to the same one? Is the map on singletons injective? Surjective?

Comment: What does "natural" mean?

Comment: I think it makes more sense if you ask the person asking you these questions for clarification than having us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea would be to define $$s_b = \{b\} \quad \forall b \in B$$ and notice that if $f:2^A\to2^B$ then you want to define $g:B \to A$ relating $g(b) $ to $f^{-1}(s_b)$.

You have to make sure this is well-defined as a function, though...

Comment: @InterstellarProbe that's impossible since $f$ preserves unions and maps $f(A)=B$ by definition.

Comment: Now that the OP has clarified, I agree with your answer.

Comment: If we set $A=\mathbb N$, $B=\mathbb R$ and $f:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$: $$f(X)=\begin{cases} \varnothing &\text{if }X=\varnothing \\ \mathbb R &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ then that satisfies the OP's condition. What would your $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb N$ be?

Comment: @HenningMakholm no good candidate here offhand, clearly all kind of structure missing from $f$. That's the job of the problem solver -- rule out such crazy $f$'s with enough conditions to make imposition of structure meaningful... The question does explicitly ask for the *conditions that guarantee the existence of a such function*